# Cambio de color de un elemento de forma dinámica

Tags: javascript, html, css

Comunidad, buen dia, quisiera saber como cambiar el color de un elemento dinamicamente con javascript, dependiendo de la hora del dia, un ejemplo:

- un negocio abre a las 8am el elemento se pone de color verde y dice abierto
- el mismo negocio se cierra a las 16pm el elemento se pone color rojo y dice cerrado

pego la linea del codigo

```
<p>Disponibilidad: <span><i class="fas fa-circle" style="color: green;"></i> Abierto</span></p>
```

muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Puedes hacerlo con el constructor [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)**

Obteniendo la hora actual y cambiando el `innerHTML` del elemento

Teniendo en cuenta que tendrás que ponerle un ID al `<p>` para poder obtenerlo con Javascript

```js
const d = new Date();
if (d.getHours() > 17) {
  disponibilidad.innerHTML = `Disponibilidad: <span style="color:green;font-weight:bolder;"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Abierto</span>`;
} else {
  disponibilidad.innerHTML = `Disponibilidad: <span style="color:red;font-weight:bolder;"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Cerrado</span>`;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
<p id="disponibilidad"></p>
```